# UseEffect Hook not triggering on page load & page refresh

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, components

I'm making an API Request in my dictionary component using the UseEffect hook with the search term as a dependency. I'm getting: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')* Nothing in the UseEffect hook is running. if I move the *getDef* function out of the hook it runs but setDefinition(res.data[0]) isn't setting the state but i can see the data in data logged in the console. The dependency is hard-coded in for the moment and I can see that it's being passed in to the Dictionary component properly from a console.log(). How do I make sure that the function fires on load and on refresh with the given search term?

Dictionary Definition:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect, } from "react";
const APIKEY = ''

const DictionaryDefinition = ({ searchTerm }) => {
    console.log(searchTerm);

    const [definition, setDefinition] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const getDef = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get(`https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/${searchTerm}?key=${APIKEY}`);
            setDefinition(res.data[0]);
            console.log(definition,'definition')
            console.log('definition')

            console.log(definition.fl)
        }
        getDef()

    }, [searchTerm])

    return (
        <div className="text-left w-1/2">
            <p className="text-4xl font-nitti">{definition.meta.id}</p>
            <p className="text-lg font-nitti">{definition.fl}</p>
            <p className="text-2xl font-nitti">{definition.hwi.prs[0].mw}</p>
            <p className="text-4xl font-spaceGrotesk">{definition.shortdef[0]}</p>

        </div>

    )


}

export default DictionaryDefinition;
```

Home.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ReactTagInput from "@pathofdev/react-tag-input";
import "@pathofdev/react-tag-input/build/index.css";
import SectionTitle from './components/SectionTitle';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import DictionaryDefinition from './components/Dictionary/DictionaryDefinition';


const Home = ({data,setData, ingredients, setIngredients}) => {
 
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);    

    return (
        <>    
            <DictionaryDefinition searchTerm={'nutmeg'}/>
           
        </>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Res from Api Call in UseEffect:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "meta": {
                "id": "nutmeg",
                "uuid": "5ccd9bd8-72d8-4bda-bf5a-7be78dc7e2f0",
                "sort": "142817000",
                "src": "collegiate",
                "section": "alpha",
                "stems": [
                    "nutmeg",
                    "nutmegs"
                ],
                "offensive": false
            },
            "hwi": {
                "hw": "nut*meg",
                "prs": [
                    {
                        "mw": "ˈnət-ˌmeg",
                        "sound": {
                            "audio": "nutmeg01",
                            "ref": "c",
                            "stat": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "mw": "-ˌmāg"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "fl": "noun",
            "def": [
                {
                    "sseq": [
                        [
                            [
                                "sense",
                                {
                                    "sn": "1",
                                    "dt": [
                                        [
                                            "text",
                                            "{bc}an aromatic seed produced by an evergreen tree ({it}Myristica fragrans{/it} of the family Myristicaceae, the nutmeg family) native to the Moluccas"
                                        ]
                                    ],
                                    "sdsense": {
                                        "sd": "also",
                                        "dt": [
                                            [
                                                "text",
                                                "{bc}the ground seed used as a spice {dx}compare {dxt|mace||2}{/dx}"
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            [
                                "sense",
                                {
                                    "sn": "2",
                                    "dt": [
                                        [
                                            "text",
                                            "{bc}a tree yielding nutmeg"
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "et": [
                [
                    "text",
                    "Middle English {it}notemigge, notemuge{/it}, ultimately from Old Occitan {it}noz muscada{/it}, from {it}noz{/it} nut (from Latin {it}nuc-, nux{/it}) + {it}muscada{/it}, feminine of {it}muscat{/it} musky {ma}{mat|muscat|}{/ma}"
                ]
            ],
            "date": "15th century{ds||1||}",
            "shortdef": [
                "an aromatic seed produced by an evergreen tree (Myristica fragrans of the family Myristicaceae, the nutmeg family) native to the Moluccas; also : the ground seed used as a spice",
                "a tree yielding nutmeg"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "",
    "headers": {
        "cache-control": "max-age=86400, public",
        "content-length": "589",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "pragma": "cache"
    },
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        },
        "method": "get",
        "url": "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/nutmeg?key=0fe1ef32-18b0-408d-a21a-f8524d8f78d5"
    },
    "request": {}
}
```

Response from Network tab:

```
[{"meta":{"id":"nutmeg","uuid":"5ccd9bd8-72d8-4bda-bf5a-7be78dc7e2f0","sort":"142817000","src":"collegiate","section":"alpha","stems":["nutmeg","nutmegs"],"offensive":false},"hwi":{"hw":"nut*meg","prs":[{"mw":"\u02c8n\u0259t-\u02ccmeg","sound":{"audio":"nutmeg01","ref":"c","stat":"1"}},{"mw":"-\u02ccm\u0101g"}]},"fl":"noun","def":[{"sseq":[[["sense",{"sn":"1","dt":[["text","{bc}an aromatic seed produced by an evergreen tree ({it}Myristica fragrans{\/it} of the family Myristicaceae, the nutmeg family) native to the Moluccas"]],"sdsense":{"sd":"also","dt":[["text","{bc}the ground seed used as a spice {dx}compare {dxt|mace||2}{\/dx}"]]}}]],[["sense",{"sn":"2","dt":[["text","{bc}a tree yielding nutmeg"]]}]]]}],"et":[["text","Middle English {it}notemigge, notemuge{\/it}, ultimately from Old Occitan {it}noz muscada{\/it}, from {it}noz{\/it} nut (from Latin {it}nuc-, nux{\/it}) + {it}muscada{\/it}, feminine of {it}muscat{\/it} musky {ma}{mat|muscat|}{\/ma}"]],"date":"15th century{ds||1||}","shortdef":["an aromatic seed produced by an evergreen tree (Myristica fragrans of the family Myristicaceae, the nutmeg family) native to the Moluccas; also : the ground seed used as a spice","a tree yielding nutmeg"]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

You are trying to render data which does not yet exists in line:

`<p className="text-4xl font-nitti">{definition.meta.id}</p>`

There is no `definition` object, nor its `meta` property, and `id` also doesn't exist. You may want to check if data is available before rendering.

2. TL;DR, do:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(yourUrl).then((res) => setDefinition(res.data[0]));
}, [searchTerm])
```

There are some explanations here:
https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/using-async-await-inside-react-use-effect-hook

Last example is something that you partially already tried, by extracting axios.get to another function and not knowing how to set state afterwards.

3. How do I make sure that the function fires on load and on refresh with the given search term?

You can create random values of searchTerm in Home component which will trigger data fetching. For example:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState();
  const searchTermExamples = [
    'nutmeg',
    'otherSearchTerm',
    'yetAnotherSearchTerm',
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {searchTermExamples.map((term) => (
        <button onClick={() => setSearchTerm(term)}>{term}</button>
      ))}
      <DictionaryDefinition searchTerm={searchTerm} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ended up doing {definition && definition.meta.id} for all of them but don't know whether that's the best way of approaching it. Didn't realise that about the async function inside useEffect so thanks for that!

Comment: Edit - this approach isn't working now, still undefined.

Comment: is it triggering the request? can you see it in browsers network tab? if so, what is the shape of the data that you are receiving, are you sure that there is a `data` property in it, and that it is an array, and that first element of that array ([0]) contains some data? you can console.log(res) just before `setDefinition` to check

Comment: I've edited it to include the console log from res and the reponse from the Network tab. It's only triggering a request once I take out any mention of `definition` in my return statement. Changed it to only return an empty and it's making the request then.